# jQuery 1.6 Make a JSON call and Handle errors

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can i make a ajax/JSON call using jquery 1.6 and handle errors gracefully if any.

If anybody could give an example, that would be great.

Comment: Have you read the documentation? http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Dont forget to mark ans as accepted if you get the info you want

Answer (score 2):

Make use of $.ajax function avaible in jquery library and you can handle error easily.

Something like this

```
 $.ajax({
                    type: "GET", //GET or POST or PUT or DELETE verb
                    url: ajaxUrl, // Location of the service
                    data: "", //Data sent to server
                    contentType: "", // content type sent to server
                    dataType: "json", //Expected data format from server
                    processdata: true, //True or False
                    success: function (json) {//On Successfull service call
                        var result = json.name;
                        $("#dvAjax").html(result);
                    },
                    error: ServiceFailed// When Service call fails
                });
```

To check deatil infomation abour the ajax method you can check this article : http://pranayamr.blogspot.com/2011/07/jquery-ajax-calling-functions.html